# Send data to websockethandler on closing connection

Tags: python, tornado

I have Tornado `websocket handler` and I am sending messages from my browser ( I have override `on_message,on_close,open`).
In javascript on close I want to send some data to handler ( to clean some storages, I am sending some numbers in json like `{'storage':22, 'time':96}` ).
How in websocket handler in tornado to receive that `closing message` ?
I looked at `close` and `on_close` but there is no option to receive data.

Comment: In `on_close`, you can't send anything from the browser JavaScript to the Tornado service, because the connection you would send things over is closed. (Of course you can have a JavaScript close handler that sends data to the JavaScript message handler, and you can have a Tornado close handler than sends data to the Tornado message handler—in both cases, it's just calling the function. But that's not what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for correctly, it's impossible.

You want to make sure that when the connection is closed, and the browser calls the `on_close` function on your client-side JavaScript code, it can send some final data to the Tornado server.

But when the connection is closed, there's no way to send any more data. That's what it means to be closed.

What you need to do is create a "quit" or similar message, at the application level. When Tornado sends a "quit" message to the JS code, then it can send its final message; when Tornado receives that message, it can close the socket. (Of course this means you need to write your code to handle the case where that "graceful shutdown" never happens because, e.g., the client machine has been vaporized by a nuclear bomb.)